# Sorting text records from the command line

Tags: sorting, vim, command-line, sed, awk

I use Linux and store my contacts in a text file in the following format separated by a line of 5 asterisk. I use Vim to open and perform basic searches. As the size of the file increases I would like to sort the contacts by 'Tag' or 'Follow Up Date'. I treat the records as if they were on an index card. This format may or not be the best for my purpose, so I am open to tips.

```
*****$
Name: Company A$
Email: companya@mail.com$
Phone: 555-555-5555$
Address:$
Business Type: Medical$
Notes:$
Follow Up Date: 12/05/2013$
Tag:  Tag6$
*****$
Name: Company B $
Email: companyb@mail.com$
Phone: 666-666-6666$
Address:$
Business Type: Food$
Notes:$
Follow Up Date: 12/03/2013$
Tag:  Tag7$
*****$
```

I understant Sed is for streams of data and Awk is for delmited fields. I am learning to use both but am unable to achieve the desired result so far. I am also learning to use Sort, basically work my file from the command line.

Can someone assist me with sorting the records by 'Tag' or 'Follow Up Date', either in Vim or right from the command line?

Thanks everyone

Comment: What does sorting by `Tag` mean? Treat the entire field value as a string to sort by?

Comment: Why cant you use a `csv`?

Comment: Why don't you use a proper Contacts / Addressbook application (I guess there are even command-line ones)?! Using Linux doesn't mean  (any more) one has to poorly reimplement everything from scratch.

Comment: I am tired of using Salesforce and other CRM's, in the end I only use the basic features. I wanted to use this opportunity to learn the command-line and its tools.

Comment: @MattM You mention you use `linux` but state the version of `awk` as `20070501` which is BSD variant (albeit a Mac version)? The solution will be much easier with `GNU awk`.

Comment: Ok, I have both systems. I'll try it on Arch and report back the results.

Comment: wrt `Sed is for streams of data and Awk is for delmited fields` - no, sed is for simple substitution on single lines of text and awk is for anything else, including multi-line records.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a perfect answer, but try reformatting the information. Keep all the information in an address card in a single record with fixed length or tab/comma separated fields. You will then be able to sort it on any field. For example:

```
|Rec0001|Name1        |email1@email.com       |091-909090990 | ......|tag1   |tag2
|Rec0002|Name2        |email2@email2.com      |091-909090991 | ......|tagx   |tagy
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand that OP need sort records (paragraph) by `follow up date`, not sort on each line.

Here is the example source file I make from OP's requirement.

```
$ cat file
*****
Name: A
Email:
Phone:
Address:
Business Type:
Notes:
Follow Up Date: 12/03/2013 
Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3
*****
Name: B
Email:
Phone:
Address:
Business Type:
Notes:
Follow Up Date: 2/28/2014
Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3
*****
```

Here is the commands to sort the two records with `follow up date`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n/,"|")}1' RS="*+\n"  file |sort -hr|awk '{gsub(/\|/,"\n");print "*****" RS $0}' 

*****
Name: B
Email:
Phone:
Address:
Business Type:
Notes:
Follow Up Date: 2/28/2014
Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3

*****
Name: A
Email:
Phone:
Address:
Business Type:
Notes:
Follow Up Date: 12/03/2013 
Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3

*****
```

#### Explanation

1) the first awk command will convert each record into one line:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n/,"|")}1' RS="*+\n"  file

Name: A|Email:|Phone:|Address:|Business Type:|Notes:|Follow Up Date: 12/03/2013 |Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3|
Name: B|Email:|Phone:|Address:|Business Type:|Notes:|Follow Up Date: 2/28/2014|Tag:  Tag1, Tag1, Tag3|
```

2)`sort -h` sort records on comparing human readable numbers

3) second awk is used to convert the record back to its original format.

Comment: Ok, the first command performed as indicated.  The second command sort -h returns "sort: invalid option -- h"  The third command returns the file to its original structure however adds 5 lines of asterisk between each record.  If the third command can get cleared up, I can figure out the sorting issue.  Thanks!

Comment: what's your awk version?

Comment: could you please provide two records for reference, and use the command `cat -A file` to show if there are any hide characters.

Comment: can you update these records in original question with format?

Comment: Ok, I replaced the text in the original question, its the output of cat -e (showing non printed characters)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a vim method similar to @BMW's answer.  The two are not exactly equivalent:  if I read @BMW's solution correctly, then it will be confused by numbers in the other fields; vim's `:sort` has limited numeric options.  (If you want to sort by date, it is simpler if you use a format like `YYYYMMDD`, with no punctuation.)

```
:v/\V*****/s/^/|
:g/\V*****/,/\V*****\|\%$/-j
:sort n /|Follow Up Date:/
:%s/|/\r/g
```

Notes:

1. I use the unpopular `\V` modifier (very no-magic) so that <kbd>*</kbd> is not treated as a special character.
2. Whether you use awk or vim, you might want to use something more distinctive than <kbd>|</kbd>.
3. The `:g` command will work properly if you have a blank line at the end of the file.  You could add and remove it as part of this process if you do not like having it there.
4. Use `:sort /|Tag:/` to sort by the tags instead of the follow-up dates.